# FabricJs Cannot read property 'className' of null

Tags: fabricjs

I just upgraded fabricJs from 1.4.0 to 1.4.13 so that i can use **SetSrc() of Image** class and when i tried to run my application i got this error :"Cannot read property 'className' of null". Here is the line of code where the error originated from

```
   const options = {
              id: client.ProfileId,
              class: 'img_wifiClient',
              left: (transX + client_left) * canvasFabric.scale,
              top: (transY + client_top) * canvasFabric.scale,
              selectable: true,
              hasBorders: false,
              hasControls: false,
              padding: 0,
              perPixelTargetFind: true,
              width: 24,
              height: 24,
              originX: 'center',
              originY: 'center'
       }

       let image = new fabric.Image('');//*This is where the error originated from*
       canvasFabric.add(image);

       let src;


       if (client.IconName === 'default.png' || client.IconName === null)
       {

              src = '/Icones/wifi.png';
       }
       else
       {

              src = `/Icones/${client.IconName}`;
       }

        image.setSrc(src, function () {
              image.setCoords();
              canvasFabric.renderAll();
         }, options);
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I added an img element with id = "myIcone" under the canvas element in the Html file and added the following lines of code and everything works.

```
 let image_element = document.getElementById('myIcone');
 let image = new fabric.Image(image_element);
 canvasFabric.add(image);
```

The rest of the code is the same as in the question snippet